# OpenCL Error Code -13 (Only on AMD)

Tags: opencl

I have an opencl kernel that only fails on AMD and not NVIDIA. It fails with error code -13

Online, it gives this explanation: "if a sub-buffer object is specified as the value for an argument that is a buffer object and the offset specified when the sub-buffer object is created is not aligned to CL_DEVICE_MEM_BASE_ADDR_ALIGN value for device associated with queue."

I am unable to figure out what does this mean. What is CL_DEVICE_MEM_BASE_ADDR_ALIGN. This routine only fails when I call createSubBuffer.

Answer (score 2):

`CL_DEVICE_MEM_BASE_ADDR_ALIGN` is a parameter to clGetDeviceInfo (see https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/clGetDeviceInfo.html for the documentation, and https://forums.khronos.org/showthread.php/9134-Looking-for-a-better-explanation-of-CL_DEVICE_MEM_BASE_ADDR_ALIGN for more explanation). You need to look at that value to determine your sub-buffer alignment.

Comment: looks like i can slice wherever i want for nvidia, but not for amd. i can only slice if the offset is divisible by the alignement.